# Powershell parsing xml logfile & get currently parsed filename

Tags: regex, xml, powershell, gridview

I'm new with powershell and in need of guidance. Been scouring the site for answers and coming up blank, decided to ask instead. If this has been answered please refer me to the link.

I have an application log (xml format) like below:

```
<log><identifier>123axr4x5</identifier><login>USER1</login><source>Order-Management</source><AddlInfo>Execution Time : 20ms</AddlInfo><Exception></Exception><timestamp>01/01/2015:22:00:00</timestamp><serverticks>643670855</serverticks><PID>1234</PID><Machine>PRD01X12mm</Machine></log>

<log><identifier>dd8jksl3g</identifier><login>USER2</login><source>Service-Assurance</source><AddlInfo>Execution Time : 80ms</AddlInfo><Exception></Exception><timestamp>01/01/2015:22:00:00</timestamp><serverticks>643680865</serverticks><PID>1234</PID><Machine>PRD01X12mm</Machine></log>
 : and so on
```

I am creating a log parser that will scan a folder and its subfolder for matching regex pattern, and based on certain threshold, output into gridview/export to CSV. I am almost done, however i'm unable to solve 1 problem, **which is to get the filename currently being parsed**, to be displayed on the gridview.

Basically i am using piped Get-ChildItem as below

```
Get-ChildItem $Dir -recurse -Filter *logging*.txt|
Sort-Object LastWriteTime | 
?{$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-60)}|
Select-String -Pattern $Text  |
Select-String -Pattern $Text3  |
Select-String -Pattern $Text2 -allmatches |
Foreach-Object { 
$information = $_|Select-Object -Property API, Duration,DataRetrieved, ServerTime, ServerTicks , Identifier, Filename 
$information.Filename = $_.Name    
#$information.Filename = $_.FullName 

} |
Out-GridView
```

Below is the full code:

```
$Dir = "C:\log\"
$threshold = 1 + 0

$StartTime = (Get-Date).ToString();
$EndTime = (Get-Date).ToString();

$Text = "abc"
$Text2 = "def"
$Text3 = "ghi"
$OutFile = "result"

$OutPath = $Dir + $OutFile + ".txt"

#ExtractionParameters
$AddlInnfoTagBegin = "AddlInfo"
$AddlInnfoTagEnd = "/AddlInfo"
$ServerTimeOfLogTagBegin = "ServerTimeOfLog"
$ServerTimeOfLogTagEnd = "/ServerTimeOfLog"
$ServerTicksTagBegin = "ServerTicks"
$ServerTicksTagEnd = "/ServerTicks"
$IdentifierTagBegin = "Identifier"
$IdentifierTagEnd = "/Identifier"

#parse file in folders
Get-ChildItem $Dir -recurse -Filter *logging*.txt|
Sort-Object LastWriteTime | 
#?{$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddMinutes(-60)}|
Select-String -Pattern $Text  |
Select-String -Pattern $Text3  |
Select-String -Pattern $Text2 -allmatches |
 Foreach-Object {

    # take line and split it at tabulators
    $parts = $_.Line

    #write $parts
    $indexOfAddlInfoBegin = $parts.IndexOf($AddlInnfoTagBegin) + $AddlInnfoTagBegin.Length +1
    $indexOfAddlInfoEnd = $parts.IndexOf($AddlInnfoTagEnd) -1

    $AddlInfoData = $parts.Substring($indexOfAddlInfoBegin, $indexOfAddlInfoEnd - $indexOfAddlInfoBegin)
    $AddlInfoReplaced = $AddlInfoData.Replace(" seconds ","@")
    $AddlInfoSplit = $AddlInfoReplaced.Split('@')
    $information = $_|Select-Object -Property API, Duration,DataRetrieved, ServerTime, ServerTicks , Identifier, Filename   

    #get filename, which does not work
    $information.Filename = $_.Name 
    #$information.Filename = $_.FullName 

    $information.API =  $AddlInfoSplit[0].Split(':')[0]

    $information.DataRetrieved =  $AddlInfoSplit[1]
    $information.Duration = $AddlInfoSplit[0].Split(':')[1]
    $information.Duration = $information.Duration.Replace("Execution Time = ","")

    $indexOfServerTimeBegin = $parts.IndexOf($ServerTimeOfLogTagBegin) + $ServerTimeOfLogTagBegin.Length +1
    $indexOfServerTimeEnd = $parts.IndexOf($ServerTimeOfLogTagEnd) -1
    $ServerTimeData = $parts.Substring($indexOfServerTimeBegin, $indexOfServerTimeEnd - $indexOfServerTimeBegin)
    $information.ServerTime = $ServerTimeData


    $indexOfServerTicksBegin = $parts.IndexOf($ServerTicksTagBegin) + $ServerTicksTagBegin.Length +1
    $indexOfServerTicksEnd = $parts.IndexOf($ServerTicksTagEnd) -1
    $ServerTickData = $parts.Substring($indexOfServerTicksBegin, $indexOfServerTicksEnd - $indexOfServerTicksBegin)
    $information.ServerTicks = $ServerTickData 

    $indexOfIdentifierBegin = $parts.IndexOf($IdentifierTagBegin) + $IdentifierTagBegin.Length +1
    $indexOfIdentifierEnd = $parts.IndexOf($IdentifierTagEnd) -1

    $IdentifierData = $parts.Substring($indexOfIdentifierBegin, $indexOfIdentifierEnd - $indexOfIdentifierBegin)
    $information.Identifier = $IdentifierData 

    $DurationAsInt = 0 + $information.Duration 
    if($DurationAsInt -gt $threshold) {
    write $information
    }
 } |
 Out-GridView
#Out-File -FilePath $OutPath -Append -Width 200
```

Any help is appreciated, thanks!!

-CL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property you are looking for is "FileName".

```
  $information.Filename = $_.FileName
```

Powershell provides a cmdlet "Get-Member" which would list all available properties/methods. You could enumerate the members to console and inspect what is available

```
  Write-Host ( $_ | Get-Member)
```

Comment: Thanks Baski! good to know about the Get-Member cmdlet, thanks again!